# Exit PowerShell Script in Task Scheduler After Successful Launch

Tags: windows, powershell

I have this this code that will run at the commandline without issue - using the -d parm it exits dynamically.   How can I get Task Scheduler to release it - or Exit to complete its Run back to a Ready state for the  task?

```
D:\TEST\psexec -s -i -d "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe" -File "D:\TEST\testrun2.ps1"
```

Comment: Why do you need to run the command using psexec in the first place?

Comment: -i is for interactive.. you don’t want that in a scheduled task.

Comment: But again: Why psexec at all? Why not just run the command directly?

Comment: Task Scheduler can run tasks as SYSTEM natively; no need for psexec here.

Comment: All comments are valid. Now for psexec when run under different contexts, don't forget the -accepteula switch